# Disable Scrolling on Magic Mouse 2 in El Capitan

Tags: macos, mouse

How can scrolling (horizontal or vertical) be disabled in El Capitan with a Magic Mouse 2?

Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Mouse Options does not contain a checkbox as described in some online articles

Comment: I would also like an answer to this... the terminal commands; `defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse MouseHorizontalScroll -bool NO`. `defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse MouseVerticalScroll -bool NO` or `defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseVerticalScroll -bool NO` `defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseHorizontalScroll -bool NO` do not seem to work